# Wine instance on Launcher

Tags: wine

I installed Wine using synaptic but when I write "Wine" in Launcher the only results are:

1. Configure Wine
2. Uninstall Wine Software
3. Winetricks

Is this normal? Shouldn't there be an instance of Wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour for about as long as I have used Wine (~4 years). Wine does not do anything by itself, it is always used for running something else:

```
$ wine
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
```

Programs installed in Wine usually get their own launchers.

Comment: N.B. It does (in versions I have used) also come with a file browser, wordpad, a mines game and a weird implementation of Internet Explorer using Gecko.

Comment: @Wilf Never saw the Mines game, but I have seen the others. Especially the hated Notepad, which often took over file associations of text files. :(

Comment: @muru you can open it using `winemine`. I also think there is some other stuff for building windows packages for Linux.